How to set up a spatial 2D initial condition in FiPy
I have been looking at the examples and documentation of FiPy, but didn't find a clear way to start a scalar field with an initial shape on it. My goal is to load a picture and use it as the value for a scalar field $S(x,y)$ at $t=0$.
So, basically, this is how I started:
from fipy import Grid2D, CellVariable, DiffusionTerm, TransientTerm
import PIL

A = np.array(PIL.Image.open('path/to/image').convert('L')) #This is the initial condition

grid = Grid2D(dx = 0.1,dy = 0.1,nx = A.shape[0],ny = A.shape[1])

S = CellVariable(name = 'S', mesh = grid, value = ???) 

Now, if I try to set value to the array A, it is going to create a enormous 3D tensor with shape (A.shape[0], A.shape[1], N) where N is a huge number. Since this is a 2D problem, I don't see why it is trying to create a 3D array (it could be time, but it didn't receive any explicit reference to it yet).
So, I want to know how to initialize the field S properly.

A FiPy Grid2D represents a 2D array of nx * ny cells, but the data is not arranged as a 2D array. The data of a CellVariable is always arranged as 0..N-1 cells. The following should work for you:
# note that A.shape[0] and A.shape[1] are swapped to make
# the data strides consistent with how the cells are they're
# laid out in FiPy
grid = Grid2D(dx = 0.1,dy = 0.1,nx = A.shape[1],ny = A.shape[0])

# A.flat returns a 1D iterator over the 2D array in A
S = CellVariable(name = 'S', mesh = grid, value = A.flat) 

